# Regex pattern to validate Linux folder path

Tags: java, regex, linux, validation, filepath

Using JAVA.
I am trying to find a more elegant way for **validating a Linux folder path** (not including the file name).

What I have so far is this: `"^\\/$|^((\\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))+)$"`

Folder paths should include only following characters: *letters*, *numbers*, *dashes* or *underscore*.

#### Test cases

Valid/ matches:

- `/`
- `/abc`
- `/abc/abc/abc/abc`

Invalid / not-matches:

- **null** or **empty string**
- `/abc/`
- `/abc/abc/abc/abc/`

Comment: Well the elegant way would be to not use regex at all and instead use the nio libraries to determine if the path is valid....

Comment: What is the use-case for your validation? Why is your RegEx not working for you? Maybe we can find a better solution besides using the RegEx :)

Comment: My pattern works, it just looks clunky, and wasn't sure I was doing it right.

Comment: Why are you limiting the folder names to alphanumeric? A folder name can contain close to any character.

Comment: Using only alphanumeric because of requirements in the application we are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Issue with your RegEx

Your supplied RegEx is working on the test-cases.

You could **even reduce it** by removing backslashes `\\` and outer pair of parentheses. Begin `^` and end `$` are only needed once (around the two alternatives).

### Possible Solution using Regular Expression

You can test the RegEx [on RegexPlanet.com](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydcfh3nr) *(click on Java-Button for tests)*

```
^/|(/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$
```

or equivalent (see demo on [RegexPlanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydcfh3nr))

```
^/|(/[\w-]+)+$
```

*Explained:* 
`\w` matches a [word-character](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#chars) (same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, not matching the *dash*).

#### Implementation in Java code:

```
public boolean isValidLinuxDirectory(String path) {
    Pattern linuxDirectoryPattern = Pattern.compile("^/|(/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$");
     return path != null && !path.trim().isEmpty() && linuxDirectoryPattern.matcher( path ).matches();
}
```

### Alternative Solution using `File`

Note the [docs on isDirectory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory--):

> ***Returns:***
>       `true` if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname **exists** and is a directory; `false` otherwise

So it may only validate your requirements (valid Linux folder) if run on a Linux machine and if the folder/directory exists.

```
public boolean isValidExistingDirectory(String path) {
     if (path == null || path.trim().isEmpty()) return false;
     File file = new File( path );
     return file.isDirectory();
}
```

### Extended Solution

As stated in comment the [special form of root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840916/what-is-path-how-is-it-different-from) `//` should also be valid. Then use this RegEx:

```
^/|//|(/[\w-]+)+$
```

It supports:

1. root-directory `/`
2. special form of root-directory `//`
3. any non-root directory, which name is composed out of alphas, numbers, dash or underscore (e.g. `/abc/123/_abc-123`)

### See also

- [What is the most correct regular expression for a UNIX file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537772/what-is-the-most-correct-regular-expression-for-a-unix-file-path)
- [Regular expression to validate windows and linux path with extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44289075/regular-expression-to-validate-windows-and-linux-path-with-extension)
- [what is path //, how is it different from /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840916/what-is-path-how-is-it-different-from)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Very helpful!

Comment: `^/|/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$` does not work for the case where the folder path is `//`.  
`^/$|^(/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$` works.

Comment: @afrey OK. Then please **UPDATE** your question for extended requirement (as I just did). Sure that your regex `^/$|^(/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$` [does match the special-root](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyut9ufyr)  (`//`) ??

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go:
`\/[a-zA-Z0-9_\/-]*[^\/]$`

**EDIT**

First character matches a forward slash `/`. The following character group matches a-z, A-Z, 0-9, underscores, forward slashes, and dashes (all accepted directory and filename characters). The following asterisk makes the pattern match that character group 0 or more times (so any combo of those characters). The last character group has a negation `^` meaning it matches anything EXCEPT what's in the character group, being the final forward slash that we don't want to match. Finally the `$` to end the string.

Comment: Also if you can actually use the filesystem take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468789/is-there-a-way-in-java-to-determine-if-a-path-is-valid-without-attempting-to-cre)

Comment: Great, but it doesn't accept "/" as a path. Here's an improvment: `^\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\/-]*[^\/])?$`

Answer (score 0):

To cover all cases including the root directory, you will need the following:

```
^\/$|(\/[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)+$
```

See [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0H4Gq9/1) using global and multiline modifiers.